# What is the oldest archaeological source which mentions a name of a specific place?

Tags: archaeology

What is the oldest archaeological source which mentions a name of a specific place?

Out of curiosity, what is that place name and what does the name mean?

Answer (score 2):

The Sumerian [Kesh temple hymn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesh_temple_hymn) identifies and describes a temple, possibly that of the town of Kish.

As long as there are older [undeciphered writing systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undeciphered_writing_systems) this answer is necessarily incomplete.